# x64 CMPPD (Compare packed 64-bit floats) instruction

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, machine-code

The CMPPD instruction (page 545 of the intel x64 manual) says it reverses the operands if you need to use greater or greater than or equal to.  That makes sense for the instruction that takes two registers but how do you swap operands for the address and register version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're either going to have load the memory operand into a register, use the inverse comparison (greater than is the equivalent of NLE except for NaNs) or use the AVX instruction (VCMPPD) which doesn't have this limitation.